# How to access other levels on destiny

Tags: ps3, destiny

I completed the first mission im rank 2 on the game, l go to the tower and it still doesn't work, please can any of you guys help me

Comment: What doesn't work? Have you talked to any NPC(s) in the tower that have a marker over them? If you open your menu and go to the Quests tab, what does it tell you to do?

Answer (score 1):

After completing the first quest, you'll be able to pick your next missions from the Explorer.  You can only select new missions by going to `orbit`.  From there you'll see a `Select Destination` button:
[image: destiny orbit]

And clicking on that will show you:

[image]

Selecting a planet or activity type will give you mission and activity options.